# What functions have the property $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$ where $A,B$ are matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

There is the classic example $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. I am looking for other examples of this property, it is best if f maps matrices to scalars but any example would be great.

Note: No need for trivial $f(A)=cA$ type functions; I am looking for something more exotic.

Comment: Take A and B be independent random events (vectors) and take f to be probability measure. What's more exotic than probability theory.

Comment: Could that idea be extended to matrices? Can you send any source of this idea?

Comment: You can replace A and B with matrices but I'm not sure if the equality would imply independent, but that's about random matrix theory which is way out of my reach. I'll just say that, the other notions other than independence, like correlation,  become more prominent in practice and the whole thing is a very vast field.

Comment: It *is* unique in some sense: every such map (from matrices to scalars) should *factor through* determinant map. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158557/do-multiplicative-maps-of-matrices-factor-through-determinants) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you want, but I think in general the functions you're describing are *homomorphisms* between a matrix group and some other group.

If you aren't familiar with groups, it's probably sufficient here to know that a group is a set with an invertible binary operation and an identity element; invertible matrices with the usual matrix multiplication are therefore an example, and this group is usually called the *general linear group*.

For example, the determinant is a homomorphism from the general linear group to the non-zero real numbers. I'm not sure if I have any examples of interesting maps, but using this terminology might make it easier for you to find some!

Comment: That is a very nice way of thinking about it, thanks! I might be able to find some useful functions from group theory textbooks

Comment: Actually, a monoid homomorphism suffices.

Comment: OP wants it for all matrices, so determinant maps from all matrices onto the reals, so strictly speaking the matrices don't form a group under multiplication, so determinant is not a homomorphism. So if OP restricts the search to homomorphisms, then OP won't find the determinant, and might miss lots of other fun examples.

Answer (score 0):

For $f:M_n(\mathbb F)\to\mathbb K$ where $\mathbb F$ and $\mathbb K$ are some fields and $M_n(\mathbb F)\ne M_2(GF(2))$, it is multiplicative if and only if $f=g\circ\det$ for some multiplicative map $g:\mathbb F\to\mathbb K$. As the other answer here has mentioned, the main idea has been outlined in Jyrki Lahtonen's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/158560) to another question. The key fact is that when $n\ne2$ or $\mathbb F\ne GF(2)$, the special linear group $SL_n(\mathbb F)$ is a commutator subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb F)$, i.e. every matrix of determinant $1$ can be expressed as a product of the form $BCB^{-1}C^{-1}$ for some $B,C\in GL_n(\mathbb F)$.

For $f:M_2(GF(2))\to\mathbb K$, it is not hard to show that $f$ is multiplicative if and only if $f=0$, $f=1$ or $f$ has the following properties:

- $f(A)=0$ for all singular matrices $A$,
- $f\left(\left\{I_2,\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&1},\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0}\right\}\right)=\{1\}$,
- $f\left(\left\{\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&1},\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1},\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\right\}\right)=\{1\}$ or $\{-1\}$.

If $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb K)=2$, such an $f$ is also in the form of $g\circ\det$ where $g:\mathbb F\to\mathbb K$ is multiplicative.

When $f:M_n(\mathbb F)\to M_m(\mathbb K)$ is matrix-valued, I don't know its characterisation. One easy example is $f(A)=\operatorname{diag}(\phi_1(A),\ldots,\phi_n(A))$ where $\phi_1,\phi_2,\ldots\phi_m$ are $m$ multiplicative maps from $M_n(\mathbb F)$ to $\mathbb K$. Since some $\phi_i$s can be taken to be zero, $f(I_n)$ can be singular but nonzero. A special case of this example (up to conjugation) is $f(A)=\phi(A)P$, where $\phi:M_n(\mathbb F)\to\mathbb K$ is a scalar-valued multiplicative map and $P\in M_m(\mathbb K)$ is a constant idempotent matrix.