# A link between multiplicative function on endomorphisms and their determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, group-homomorphism

Take $E$ a $K$-vector space with $K$ a field with characteristic $0$. Then take
$$
F:\operatorname{End}_K(E) \to K
$$
a map such that
$$F(1)=1$$
and
$$
F(\phi\circ\psi) = F(\phi)F(\psi)
$$
Then there exists a $f:K \to K$ such that is multiplicative and $F(\phi) = f(\det\phi)$ for any $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_K(E)$.

This is an exercise by *Linear Algebra* of Werner Greub and the hint is
[image]

Can anyone give me a way to go from the hint to the answer? I have thought to write any endomorphism using the maps he introduces but the expression I find is not so clear in terms of determinant

Comment: Is there a typo in the equation involving $F(\phi) F(\psi)$? It looks tautological.

Comment: @sammyblack It is a typo. It should be $F(\phi \circ \psi) = F(\phi) F\psi).$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158557/do-multiplicative-maps-of-matrices-factor-through-determinants

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A question about determinants an multilinear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681829/a-question-about-determinants-an-multilinear-algebra)